# Rails3 - How to make a submit button for a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using SimpleForm in Rails 3. How do I make the submit button for this nested resource?

```
resources :schools do   
  resources :students
end

<%= simple_form_for @student do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

If I use `f.submit`:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `students_path' for #<#<Class:0x000001040ddfb8>:0x000001040d2578>):
1: <%= simple_form_for @student do |f| %>
2:     <%= f.input :first_name %>
3:     <%= f.input :last_name %>
4:     <%= f.submit %>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The right code for the view is:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@school, @student] do |f| %>
     <%= f.input :first_name %>
     <%= f.input :last_name %>
     <%= f.button :submit  %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `<%= f.submit %>` instead of `<%= f.button :submit %>`

Comment: Your result is unrelated to this current question so please ask that in another question. And if my answer worked for you, you should maybe upvote and accept it :)

Comment: It didn't work. I got the same error than before. In rake route I see:                      PUT    /schools/:school_id/students/:id(.:format)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how or where, you are setting the @school.
if @school is nil the above answer may not work.

However you can also use

```
<%= simple_form_for [:school, @student] do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :first_name %>
 <%= f.input :last_name %>
 <%= f.submit  %>
<% end %>
```